# Making new field with formatted values without leading zeros in QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, fields-attributes, string, formatting, leading-zero

I have a field called `"Kiinteistotunnus"`. The values ​​are of the form 73499900010025. The values ​​should be split into parts in style 734-999-0001-0025. But what should I do if I want values ​​without leading zeros in the format 734-999-1-25?

Comment: Have you tried using `regexp_replace()`?

Comment: Do you want store the data as integer value `73499900010025` or as already formatted string `734-999-0001-0025`?

Comment: as a formatted string 734-999-1-25

Comment: I need it to be in a right format 734-999-1-25

Comment: What is the data type of the `Kiinteistotunnus`? String, integer, float other?

Comment: Kiinteistotunnus field is a Integer

Comment: Values itself in 'Kiinteistotunnus' is divided as follows ###-###-####-####. the value can therefore have a varying number of leading zeros.

Comment: Is the ID certainly integer so that the first part of three signs (here `734`) cannot contain leading zeroes?

Comment: the first part doesn't contain any leading zeros

Comment: In my file there's just 734 parcels.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This will cause an error if the length of your integer values is different from `73499900010025`.**

Looks horrible but it works (replace `73499900010025` with `"Kiinteistotunnus"`):

```
with_variable( 'val', to_string(73499900010025), 
 
to_int(substr(@val,0, 3))
|| '-' ||
to_int(substr(@val,4, 3))
|| '-' ||
to_int(substr(@val,7, 4))
|| '-' ||
to_int(substr(@val,11, 4))
)
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect. thanks a lot

Comment: @Jussi.S. You can accept the answer if it solves your problem and your question will be closed.